# AR Camera pointers? How to position and implement smooth target tracking?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm new to AR and I've read this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-ar-android-app-with-vuforia-and-unity/ and search for other tutorials as well so far I haven't found a topic where the you can rotate your camera around the target. I want to be able to rotate/move my camera around the target and expect that the model will also rotate according to the camera's position. Currently I am using Extended Tracking it is almost working the way I want it to but its jittery and the model moves away from the target where it should stay. I also can't rotate around the target, the model gets stuck on the screen if i do this and doesn't respond to the current movement/position of the camera.  I'm using Vuforia for this project.

Comment: If you want to move around a virtual object, you'll need something like (Project) Tango or Hololens which has extra depth sensors to allow for spatial tracking.

Comment: Forget about Hololens, it is only for developer in the US/Canada at the moment and is $3000.

Comment: Trying to understand what you are asking... Do you want your model to follow your movements? It is possible that your model can always face you. You are gonna have to shoot a line and turn your model accordingly, quite simple if you are using Unity

Comment: Hi @firativerson , thanks for answering my question. Its not that I want it to always face me. Its just that if I move my camera, I want the model to stay put in the target and I can see the sides of my model or the back of it, depending on where I move.